# Bash export ignores set -ex

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

I've run into some strange behaviour today:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -ex
export a=$(cat foo)
echo "It's a living thing"
b=$(cat foo)
echo "This won't make it"
```

This won't stop on `cat foo` even though `foo` does not exist. But without the export, it fails. Why?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In:

```
a=$(cmd)
```

That's a simple command without command part, so the exit status is that of the command substitution instead. In:

```
a=$(cmd) export a
```

or

```
export a="$(cmd)"
```

There is a command part here (even if in some shells, `export` is midway between a command and a keyword), so its exit status is returned. If `cmd` fails and produces no output `export a=` will still be run and succeed, so `export` will return a 0 exit status.

Here you'd want:

```
a=$(cmd)
export a
```

Or even better, get rid of that unreliable `set -e` and do proper error handling by hand:

```
a=$(cmd) || exit
export a
```

See e.g. [BashFAQ 015: "Why doesn't set -e do what I expected?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) for further examples of why and how `set -e` can produce unexpected results.

Comment: See for instance http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ#BashFAQ.2F105.Why_doesn.27t_set_-e_.28or_set_-o_errexit.2C_or_trap_ERR.29_do_what_I_expected.3F

Comment: ITYM http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105